# Write an entire html table to a text file

Tags: python

I'm attempting to download a table from a site and bring it in to a table.  I can see the output in interpreter however when I write the text file it only has one line.  How do I write the entire table to a text?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2,cookielib
import time

mech = Browser()
mech.set_handle_robots(False)
mech.set_handle_equiv(True)
mech.set_handle_redirect(True)
mech.set_handle_robots(False)
mech.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

url = "http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/index/positions/all/shipid:415660/mmsi:354975000/shipname:ADESSA%20OCEAN%20KING/_:6012a2741fdfd2213679de8a23ab60d3"

page = mech.open(url)
#html = page.read()

DateTime = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M")
Month = time.strftime ("%mm-%Y")

html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table",attrs={"class":"table table-hover text-left"})


for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    items = row.text.replace(u"kn","")# remove kn so items line up when unpacking
    time, ais_source, speed_km, lat, lon, course = items.split()[1:7]
    data = items.split()[1:7]
    text_file = open(DateTime + '.txt',"w")
    text_file.write(str(data))
    text_file.close()
    print items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(DateTime + '.txt',"a") as text_file:
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        items = row.text.replace(u"kn","")# remove kn so items line up when unpacking
        time, ais_source, speed_km, lat, lon, course = items.split()[1:7]
        data = items.split()[1:7]
        text_file.write(str(data))
        print items
```

Open the file in append mode, otherwise you are overwriting the contents of the file each loop and thus losing previous data written.

Comment: that does write all of the files to a text but it does not preserve the table formatting that is being done with .split.  which can be seen with print data

Comment: does adding a newline help? i.e. text_file.write(str(data)+'\n')

Comment: You don't need the `+` unless you are reading from the file also, the list is also being written to the file not the actual data

Comment: You don't need to open in append mode "a" unless you want to preserve what is in the file to start with. As long as you open the file outside the loop, "w" will result in all your lines being written to the file.

Comment: As far as formatting, you are printing out items and writing str(data), so naturally that will have rather different formatting. If you could clarify what format you want in the file, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the file on every pass through the loop, in mode "w" which means write (i.e. overwrite whatever is currently in the file). I recommend you open the file before the loop and close it after the loop. You could also open it in append mode on every pass through the loop.

```
with open(DateTime + '.txt',"w") as text_file:
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        items = row.text.replace(u"kn","")# remove kn so items line up when unpacking
        time, ais_source, speed_km, lat, lon, course = items.split()[1:7]
        data = items.split()[1:7]
        text_file.write(str(data))
```

Comment: with open() is more pythonic, so I changed this example to use that as per chris' answer below. You don't need to open the file in append mode if it's outside the loop, unless you want to preserve whatever is already in the file before you write to it.